# jQuery Masonry images show up on one line

Tags: jquery

Hey everybody, I'm just in the middle of developing my theme to PyroCMS and I currently have a problem that all images show up on one line. When I however disable masonry.js, it works normally.

Anyhow, check out the problem on my site here: http://askonomm.com/galleries/2010

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the imageLoaded plugin to fix this or masonry is executed before images and so it can't extract the real sizes of your blocks.